# Since the variance matrix is the expected value of a dyadic tensor, why is it not singular? Which is the probabilistic property behind that?

Tags: random-variables, covariance, exterior-algebra, variance, tensor-rank

I will try to explain better my annoying doubt.

The variance matrix (or covariance matrix, according to an alternative notation) $\Sigma_v \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of the vector random variable $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as:
$$\mathrm{V}[v]=\mathrm{E}[(v-\mathrm{E}[v])(v-\mathrm{E}[v])^T]$$
which is the expectation of the dyadic product $(v-\mathrm{E}[v])(v-\mathrm{E}[v])^T$.

Since performing this product results in columns (or rows) which are linearly dependent, this term should have rank 1 at most, and so also the expectation of it. Why is this not happening in the case of a variance matrix?

I would like to add an example of what I am trying to say: let us consider a vector random variable with three components: 
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
  v_1  \\
  v_2  \\
  v_3  
 \end{pmatrix} \mathrm{E}[v]= \begin{pmatrix}
  \bar v_1  \\
  \bar v_2  \\
  \bar v_3  
 \end{pmatrix}$$

the matrix inside the expected value of the variance will be:
$$ (v-\mathrm{E}[v])(v-\mathrm{E}[v])^T=\begin{pmatrix}
  (v_1-\bar v_1)^2 & (v_1-\bar v_1)(v_2-\bar v_2) & (v_3-\bar v_3)(v_1-\bar v_1) \\
  (v_1-\bar v_1)(v_2-\bar v_2)& (v_2-\bar v_2)^2 & (v_2-\bar v_2)(v_3-\bar v_3)\\
  (v_3-\bar v_3)(v_1-\bar v_1) & (v_2-\bar v_2)(v_3-\bar v_3) & (v_3-\bar v_3)^2
 \end{pmatrix} $$
which, without knowing anything about the random variables, should not have full rank, since the second column, for instance, can be written as the first column multiplied by $$\frac{(v_2-\bar v_2)}{(v_1-\bar v_1)}$$
and the determinant is:
$$\det(\Sigma_v ) = (v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2 - (v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2 - (v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2 -\left[(v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2-(v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2-(v_1-\bar v_1)^2(v_2-\bar v_2)^2(v_3-\bar v_3)^2\right] = 0$$
I really cannot see where is the bug in my reasoning, but I think it has to be a probabilistic matter... I truly hope someone could help me.

PS:maybe my tags are not perfectly matching the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For two singular matrices $A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}1&0\\0&0 \end{array}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{array}{ll}0&0\\0&1 \end{array}\right]$, the sum of them is not singular.

Comment: The expectation is not always a 'sum', and even when the random variable is discrete, the expectation becomes a matrix with different summations in each component, according to the actual pdf. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean you can not deduce that the expectation matrix is singular by using the fact that every matrix is singular for all $\omega$.

Comment: You are right, by integrating or summing each component with suitable different weights (according to the density function), the resulting matrix is not necessarily similar to the starting one, thank you for the help.